# how to have chown only effect folders, not files?

Tags: command-line, chmod, find, pipe

I have to chmod a structure of subfolders which contain more sufolders and also files naturally.

Now I need to change access rights (owner:group, no acl at this point) to this complete structure in the same manner. Only I want 775 for folders but 664 for files. How can I achieve that? `man chown` does not seem to give a solution, so I thought a pipe of `find` and `chown` could do it.
My knowledge of pipes is pretty basic. I think you give a command and sent the output of that command through the second command.

```
find -type d | chmod -R 775 *
```

is my guess but does not respect the output of my `find` command. Probably the '*' in the chown command overrules the output of `find` somewhat

any ideas how to tweak this in my favor?

Comment: tried this but again all files are being affected as well, not only the folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Don't* use the `-R` flag with `chmod`, which makes it recursive (applicable to all folders and files contained in the arguments). Use:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

Comment: are you sure about the dot? `find -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +` (without any dot) works pretty well. I haven't tested your version because the dotless came up earlier somewhere

Comment: @vrms the GNU version of `find` defaults to searching the current directory if no paths are given: however I'm not sure that all flavours of `find` do: the `.` may make the command more portable

Comment: @vrms I'm pretty sure of it. If no path is specified, the current directory is assumed. But that depends on the version of find, so I prefer to specify it explicitly.

Comment: @muru: thanks for the details .... actually it helped me understand how to search for something in any other directory then the one you actually are in at the very moment ... I know, `man find` would have taught me that as well. I just didn't get it before. ... So, double thumbs up !

Answer (score 0):

Update: I misread, see @muru's don't use -R
This might work:

```
chmod 775 $(find -type d)
```

It is called [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)

Comment: tried that as well, but again files are being changed by chmod also, not only directories. As this now happens with all solutions I begin to wonder whether this has any other cause? I became root before with sudo -i (because due to my access problem I couldn't access those places with my admin user). Can this be part of the problem? Wouldn't really make sense to me but ... who knows)